# How often does the MS Teams connector (Incoming WebHook) URL expire/update?

Tags: azure-data-factory, microsoft-teams, webhooks, office365connectors

There are 3 channels in MS Teams, each configured with an Incoming WebHook connector. The URL of all the 3 connectors are passed as 3 global parameter in Azure Data Factory. The connector was created around 21st June 2021 and on 23rd June 2023, the URL of all the 3 connectors got changed. They no longer matched with the URLs passed as the global parameters.

Tried looking for online articles which specifies when these connector URLs get updated. There was no notification as such saying that the earlier URL is getting updated/expired.

Comment: AFAIK, Once you create an Incoming Webhook connector in Microsoft Teams, the generated URL remains valid until you manually delete or remove the connector.

Comment: @jarvis Rebello - We got the following update - There was a security update during 2021 from Connectors team to prevent e filtration and all URLs were updated with tenant name. Also notifications were sent to users regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, In order to enable systems to transmit notifications and data to particular channels in Microsoft Teams, webhook URLs are designed to be durable and consistent.

> It's uncommon for these URLs to alter without the user's knowledge or active consent.

**The URL get updated or modified only when you manually delete, remove or modify the functionality of connector.**

**To resolve your issue,** you need to first **check If any adjustments were made to the connections** or associated Microsoft Teams settings, this could have changed the URLs. **If it got updated, you'll need to update the URLs** with the new values in ADF Global parameters.

If you are still facing an issue, you can raise support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket) for deeper investigation.